# jQueryMobile - form styling (drop down icon)

Tags: html, css, forms, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I'm developing a mobile version of a website (this is the mobile version: http://web.n8geeks.com/recherche.html) and cannot seem to get the default jQueryMobile form stylings to be applied to my form. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, but obviously i'm doing something wrong as the style classes are not being applied to my form elements.

The forms should resemble the forms seen here; http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/ but as you can see, they do not.

At the moment i have custom styles for the form elements, which is fine, until i discovered the difficulty in changing the default browser-specific drop down ICON. I either need to a) use the jQueryMobile styles for the form(s) or b) figure out how to change the drop-down icons to a different icon using HTML/CSS.

So if anyone can help me either change the drop-down form icon or get the jQueryMobile forms working i'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

For the standard jQuery Mobile form styling, make sure you're including the jQM CSS file, eg:

`<link href="Content/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

And also make sure you're not including another CSS file *after* your jQM CSS file that's overwriting the standard jQM stuff.  If so, try moving your custom CSS include above the standard jQM CSS include.